# How to loop without getting IndexError on python?

Tags: python, loops, indexing

I tried to loop for `url_data`. `url_data` is an array of strings. I get an `IndexError` that reads:

```
keywords[i]=urlparse.urlparse(url_data[i])
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

My code:

```
import os
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas
import urlparse
from numpy import genfromtxt

os.chdir("C:\Users\EDAWES01\Desktop\Cookie profiling")
data = pandas.read_csv('activity_url.csv', delimiter=';')
data_read=np.array(data)
quantity = data_read[:, 2]
url_data = data_read[quantity==1][:,1] 
url_data #extract URL data

keywords=[]

for i in url_data:
  keywords[i]=urlparse.urlparse(url_data[i])
  keywords[i]=keywords[2] #this is the path element
  keywords[i]=keywords[i].split("/")

keywords
```

Comment: `keywords` is initialized to an empty list.  So there are no valid indices.  The loop tries to use `i` as an index, multiple times, but (1) `i` apparently isn't an integer and (2) even if it were, it would be out of range since they're *all* out of range for an empty list.

Comment: `keywords` is a error. But the error message is about `url_data[i]`. `url_data` and `i` are `str`.  `str[str]` won't work

Answer (score 1):

try this loop instead

```
for i in xrange(0,len(url_data)):
     keywords[i]=urlparse.urlparse(url_data[i])
```

Comment: `xrange(len(list))` is not the pythonic way.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong. If you want both the element and index, use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html).

```
for idx,url in enumerate(url_data):
    keywords[idx]=urlparse.urlparse(url_data[idx])
    # or it could be
    keywords[idx]=urlparse.urlparse(url)  
    # both of these will still raise IndexError for keywords
```

Now, coming to the issue of `keywords` which is an empty `list` so you'll get `IndexError` for that too. I think you want to do the following instead.

```
keywords.append(urlparse.urlparse(url))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your code keywords should be either:

```
keywords = {}
keywords = dict()
```

`print(i)` to figure out what you're doing.